# Is ISP sending WiFi password in plain text to phone necessarily a bad sign?

Tags: passwords, password-management, sms, isp

The new router I was given by my internet and phone provider can only be configured via their website. I logged in and went to the page where you can set things like the SSID and password for the WiFi signal, and changed some of the settings. The changes were accepted and everything works fine.

However, later I noticed that they had sent an automated text message to my phone, which had the WiFi password in plain text. This surprised me, because I have always been told that sending passwords in plain text is a sign of unprofessional security arrangements. However, this is one of the biggest ISP's in my (European) country, with millions of clients and decades of experience, and I can't imagine that their security is amateurish.

**Is there a way in which sending passwords in plain text in a text message to a phone is not a security risk?** Maybe they only store it temporarily after the settings have changed, and it is wiped after being sent? Maybe sending it by text is less of a problem than sending it over the internet? Maybe a WiFi password is less of a problem because a hacker would have to physically come to my house to do anything with it? Or is this ISP indeed not following best practices?

Comment: We have had a few questions like this over the years: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175418/my-isp-shows-my-wifi-password-on-their-public-site-in-plain-text-should-i-be-wo and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/256551/how-to-handle-a-router-from-an-apparently-security-indifferent-isp-with-no-possi and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220580/isp-provider-does-not-giving-permission-to-change-my-router-password

Comment: Many ISPs store and even manage customer router settings. Is it secure for ***you***? No. But it is a major convenience for them as it simplifies their help desk processes.

Comment: @schroeder Thanks for the links. Would you say this is a common practice used by many ISP's around the world?

Comment: In France, ISPs usually print the WiFi password on a sticker that’s on the back of the router (or use WPS). It then can be changed through a local access (through WiFi or cable). The new password is not shared with the ISPs. In case of an issue, the procedure is to reset the router and its password to its default random value. Even though the router’s administration interface is accessed by a URL like myrouter.myisp.fr, this is a redirection to the router’s local webserver, only accessible though the LAN.

Comment: I would say that it's not unusual, not necessarily "common practice".

Comment: Any user with concerns over an attacker sophisticated enough to read their SMS and then use that to access their wifi would should change their wifi password from its default anyway.

Comment: @AdamKatz That's the thing, the password they sent me was a new one I had chosen, not the default one.

Comment: @A.Hersean Indeed, that's the procedure I was used to until they gave me this new router.

Comment: Ooh, that's different. If the router is advertising the password, that does indeed sound like a bad sign. A simple solution would be to disable wifi and plug a second wifi router in via ethernet, then configure that second router for your users.

Comment: never ever run a WAP or router not managed by you.